# unrecognized expression: :[type=checkbox] with jQuery 1.8

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, sizzle

I update the code to jQuery 1.8 and I start getting this error:

```
unrecognized expression: :[type=checkbox]
```

Of course this is say that the expression `:[type=checkbox]` is not recognized by the new version of jQuery and my question is:

**I have type it the wrong way, or it's a bug** ?

I have make this version for test on jsFiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/4y8tb/6/ , open the console to see the log, and if you change the jQuery version you see it one to work and one not.

I have try some other syntax (like `:[type="checkbox"]`)  but fails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('input:[type=checkbox]')
```

To:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]')
```

You are using [`Attribute Equals`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector, the syntax should be:

```
$('element[attribute="value"]')
```

Comment: +1 Thank you, this is the one. (and Andy is work, but this is close to my code).

Answer (score 6):

jQuery has an own pseudoselector for checkboxes:

```
$(':checkbox')
```